# variable value, after ternary operator

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I have these lines of code:

```
int a = 10, b = 1;
a = --b ? b : (b = -99);
        cout << "a= " << a <<  "b= " <<b<< endl;
```

the output gives me b=-99 as a is not equal to 0(which makes senses) but it also changes the value of a to a=-99 how?

Comment: If `b` is initially `1`, the expression `--b ? b : (b = -99)` has the result obtained by evaluating `(b = -99)`   i.e.   `-99`.   That is the result that is assigned to `a`.

Comment: *"as a is not equal to 0"* The value of `a` is never evaluated in that line of code; it is only assigned the result of the ternary expression, so I have no idea what that statement even means.

Comment: Did you mean to write `a == --b`?

Comment: wait so what is the condition? @WhozCraig

Comment: The ternary expression is `--b ? b : (b = -99);`. The result of that is assigned to `a`. The value of `a` is never evaluated anywhere in that expression, so I have no idea what you mean when you say "the output gives me b=-99 as a is not equal to 0". `a` is never evaluated until output. Or was *that* what you were referring to? Even then, I still don't follow what you are trying to say.

Comment: @WhozCraig yes you are right, I made a mistake thinking that "a" was evaluated in the expression, so I understand that now but. What does --b actually mean? How is that a condition?

Answer (score 4):

Your code is the equivalent of:

```
int a = 10, b = 1;
b -= 1; // b == 0
int x;
if (b != 0) x = b;
else x = b = -99;
a = x;
// at this point a and b have the same value
```

Answer (score 3):

The ternary operator works as follows:

```
if (--b != 0) { // b is not 0 means true
    a = b;
} else { // b is 0 means false
    a = (b = -99);
}
```

You assign the value to a, so --b is 0 which is considered as false. Then you assign to b value -99 and afterward, you assign b to a. So, both variables have their values -99 in the end. Hope it will help you.

Comment: `a` is never compared to `--b` in the OP

Comment: You are right, but he wrote a is not equal to 0(which is --b), so I thought that he wanted to compare it.

Comment: What the OP wants and what happens are two different things.

Answer (score 1):

According to `ternary operator`, The first argument is a comparison argument(condition), the second is the result upon a true comparison, and the third is the result upon a false comparison. 
So In Your case, the condition is `not True`, So the false statement get executed.
so now `b has -99.`
In c, c++, java we've seen, assigns the value of the variable

```
a = b = -99
```

In this, the both `a & b` gets the same value. Like this, ternary operator also assigning the value of the variable from false statement .

```
(a = (b = -99 ))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what is confusing you here is that, in `C`, an **expression** (such as `b = -99`) has both *consequences* and a *value*. The *consequence* of `b = -99` is that `b` is assigned the value of `-99`; but note also that the *value* of this expression is `-99`.

Thus, in a ternary expression, which takes the general form:

```c
lhs = test ? v_if_true : v_if_false;
```

the *expression* `test` is first evaluated and `lhs` is assigned either `v_if_true` (if `test` evaluates to non-zero) or `v_if_false` (if `test` evaluates to zero).

In your case, `test` is `--b`. The *consequence* of this expression is that the value of `b` is decreased by one, and the *value* of the expression is the resulting (modified) value of `b` (which will be zero in your code).

So, your ternary expression assigns to `a` the *value* of the `v_if_false` expression which is `b = -99` (the brackets you give add clarity to the expression, but don't change its evaluation). So, as mentioned above, this expression (as well as modifying `b`) also has a calculated *value* of `-99`, which is then given to `a`.

If you wanted to leave `a` unchanged in the case when the `v_if_false` expression is executed, then you could do this using the *comma operator*, as follows (though I would **not** recommend using such code):

```c
a = --b ? b : ((b = -99), a); // If --b == 0, this becomes a = a
```

This works because the *value* of an expression containing the comma operator is the value of the sub-expression ***after*** (to the right of) the comma.

Comment: okay but I do not understand how the condition works,because it is just --b, so how is that actually a condition?

Comment: The `test` (as I have called it above) condition can be ***any*** valid `C` expression: it could be `b == 0` (which is an *obvious* condition) or, simply `b` (this type is used a lot to abbreviate `if (a != 0)` down to `if (a)`). Neither of these *expressions* have *consequences* in themselves. Your `--b` ***does*** have a consequence … but it's still an **expression** with a *value*. The 'condition' is, essentially, the *value* of the expression. Does this help?